# Not able to get select value in scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have code like one attached in js fiddle. It is very basic, I am trying to get value of the select when it changes using scope variable. But i am not able to.Is there any specific reason why it is not working.

```
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select
            ng-model="myOption"
            ng-options="value.id as value.label group by value.group for value in myOptions" ng-change="selectedValue()">
                <option>--</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            ng-model value: {{myOptionnew}}
        </div>
    </div>

var app = angular.module('myExample', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myOptions = [{
            "id": 106,
            "group": "Group 1",
            "label": "Item 1"
        },{
            "id": 107,
            "group": "Group 1",
            "label": "Item 2"
        },{
            "id": 110,
            "group": "Group 2",
            "label": "Item 3"
        }];

    $scope.selectedValue = function()
    {
        alog($scope.myOption);   
        $scope.myOptionnew = $scope.myOption;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jm6of9bu/1107/

Answer (score 1):

In the fiddle the function `alog` is not defined. Therefore the assignment that follows doesn't occur.

Remove `alog` or replace it with `$log.log` : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm6of9bu/1110/)

As a side note, you also need to add `value=""` to the default empty option if you want it to be displayed:

```
 <option>--</option>
```

should be:

```
<option value="">--</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select
    ng-model="myOption"
    ng-options="value.id as value.label group by value.group for value in myOptions">
        <option>--</option>
</select>
<div>
    ng-model value ID: {{myOptionnew}}
</div>
```

JS :

```
    var app = angular.module('myExample', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myOptions = [{
            "id": 106,
            "group": "Group 1",
            "label": "Item 1"
        },{
            "id": 107,
            "group": "Group 1",
            "label": "Item 2"
        },{
            "id": 110,
            "group": "Group 2",
            "label": "Item 3"
        }];

     $scope.$watch('myOption', function(result){
            if (result)
            $scope.myOptionnew = result;
        });
};
```

I used $watch try this!